# Angular,jquery, posting file to c# web api, error uploadinfg unsuported media type

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image, asp.net-web-api

Hi I'm trying to send post request with image to my web api, but I have returned that error: Error "uploading unsuported media type". I don't know how to avoid this error. Some of code:
ap.js

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (element) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $(element)[0].files[0]);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:56392/api/Image',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        contentType: false,
        header: {
            'Accept': undefined,
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            alert('Error uploading: ' + errorMessage);
        }
    });
};
```

.html file

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" />
```

I builded web api in c# mvc5, but request dont even leave my page.

UPDATE I change my app.js to

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (element) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $(element)[0].files[0]);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:56392/api/Image',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,



        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            alert('Error uploading: ' + errorMessage);
        }
    });
};
```

And now i have error in my webapi ;) so request pass ;) In webapi i try to do something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(HttpPostedFile profileImage)
    {
        string[] extensions = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".bmp", ".png" };
        if (!extensions.Any(x => x.Equals(Path.GetExtension(profileImage.FileName.ToLower()), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        // Other code goes here

        return "/path/to/image.png";
    }
```

But parameter HttpPostedFile profileImage is always null. Any idea How i should do this post?

Comment: `content-type: undefined` probably shouldn't be there. Also, it does seem like the request is leaving your page as the alert is within the error section of the ajax method, which doesn't fire unless it receives an error response back

Comment: Yes, i should type that i get error in alert. So its problem with web api? or wchich content-type I should choose to post an image?

Comment: Probably a problem with the web api. Try removing the `header` property from the object you pass into `.ajax()` and see what happens

Comment: Post updated, but now i have problem with my http ost method in my webapi. I write something below EDIT.

Comment: try adding `contentType: false` and `processData: false` to your ajax object. That _might_ fix it

Comment: When I add "contentType: false," I get "error uploading: Unsuported Media Type"

Comment: Ok, remove `contentType` but keep `processData`